# Replace "prevent" with something weaker

Tags: single-word-requests

I have this sentence.

> Method A prevents the model from reaching a poor solution.

but I am trying to replace the word **prevent** with something "weaker" because method A does not prevent the model from reaching a poor solution, it just makes it harder for the model to reach that poor solution. However, I am not sure if the sentence below is grammatically correct.

> Method A makes it harder for the model from reaching a poor solution.

Forgive my English its not good.

Comment: The whole sentence seems bad to me. How does a model reach a solution?

Comment: "Inhibit" is a possible term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbs "[to hamper](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hamper_1?q=hamper)", "[to hinder](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hinder?q=hinder)" do not imply a total stop to the process represented by their object and so would suit fairly well the purpose. As well, "[to impede](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/impede?q=impede)", provided the context is clear, does not imply a total stop.

A slight modification is necessary, though.

- Method A hinders the model in its reaching a poor solution.

Answer (score 3):

As another answer mentioned, your second sentence would be more properly rephrased as:

> Method A makes it harder for the model to reach a poor solution.

However, it appears that you are describing the expected outcome of a modeling process. If so, it sounds more natural to talk about the probability of the outcome. For example:

> Method A *reduces the likelihood* of the model reaching a poor solution.

Comment: 'Harder' is the more common English usage. Impedes, hinders, hampers (verbs) are also true, but less common, although sometimes the use of less common language is considered to be 'more educated' in academic writing, 'Reduces the likelihood is a good middle ground.

As I say, it is commonplace in English academia to avoid the simplest word in a hunt for greater precision. In the example, any of the other posters solutions is fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about the verbal phrase **keep from**. From Lexico:

> **[keep from](https://www.lexico.com/definition/keep_from)**: Avoid doing something.

Your example:

> Method A **keeps** the model **from** reaching a poor solution.

This sounds weaker than *prevent*, and based on my experience, I would prefer it over words like *hamper*, *hinder*, and *impede*, which no modeler I know would use.

If there is no chance the model could reach a poor solution under Method A, I see nothing wrong with *prevent*. If there is some chance the model could reach a poor solution under Method A, your best option is that suggested by @MDK, i.e., "Method A *reduces the likelihood* of the model reaching a poor solution.